# php-fpm processes falls in Uninterruptible sleep

Tags: php, ps, server-load

I got nagios critical warning about a server, and when i checked `ps -aux` i found that all of nginx (php-fpm) are in Uninterruptible sleep

```
www-data  1330  0.4  0.3 299992 108560 ?       D    16:06   0:16 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1338  0.4  0.2 254728 92728 ?        D    16:06   0:16 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1346  0.4  0.3 293544 100272 ?       D    16:06   0:17 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1356  0.7  0.3 302504 101532 ?       D    16:06   0:29 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1357  0.3  0.2 270672 85952 ?        D    16:06   0:13 php-fpm: pool www
....
```

and i was stuck with it and couldn't even restart nginx. and finally i restart the server to fix the issue! and today the problem happened again and i managed to restart php5-fpm which reduces the server load from 300 to 1.XX
although I have this in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

```
emergency_restart_threshold=10
emergency_restart_interval=1m
process_control_timeout=10s
```

which means that php5-fpm is supposed to restart in such cases, but it didn't!!
any idea of what might cause those processes to go in uninterruptible sleep status and how to avoid such case in future?

Comment: Actually, server load 300 isn't normal. I think, this is the main reason, why your php-fpm proccesses have worked wrong. Did you see php-fpm error log? Try to enable debug mode for all php-fpm pools

Comment: as i mentioned,,, php5-fpm was causing this load. it became less than 2 once i restarted php5-fpm

Comment: It could be possible, that some php module hold whole php-fpm child. Do you have any non-standart php modules? Where did you get php-fpm(from rpm packet or compiled from source)? Try to get source & compile php for your own needs.

Comment: @SergeiLomakov I got it using apt-get. i dont have any non-standard module... i know it is a very strange case!!

Answer (score 2):

*Uninterruptible Sleep* translates to I/O. A process in this state **does not handle signals**. Thus, PHP-FPM can not restart a process that is in this state.

You probably have a bad hard drive, stale/dead network mount (nfs, cifs?) the PHP scripts are trying to access, or a really bad case of I/O contention.

Also, this is not related to [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) at all.

Comment: do you mean that emergency_restart_threshold=10,
emergency_restart_interval=1m, and 
process_control_timeout=10s will not work for D processes

Comment: Yes. It is called _uninterruptible_ sleep for a reason. ;-) See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28operating_system%29#Uninterruptible_sleep

Comment: Is there any way to automatically restart php-fpm if this happens ?